# How do I create a triangle with rounded corner?

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes

I have to create a shape like this

[image]

I will be creating a rounded rectangle and placing the triangle at the centre bottom of the rectangle.

So far I have my rectangle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#001E33" />
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

I created a upside triangle

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%"
        android:toDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

How do I make the triangle point down and how do I club these 2 files to make a single drawable?

Answer (score 0):

Draw it in Adobe illustrator(or other similar software) and use svg file format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
       android:left="40dp"
        android:right="40dp">

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="100dp"
                    android:height="100dp"/>
                <padding android:bottom="30dp"
                    />
                <stroke
                    android:width="30dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <solid android:color="#001E33" />
                <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>

        <solid android:color="#001E33" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

We can add multiple shape items inside layer list.